# I am getting Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PROC_GMAPSDATA, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PROC_GMAPSDATA, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

for my code here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_GMAPSDATA
    (@DEVICENUMBER INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DEVICEID INT

    SET @DEVICEID = (SELECT DEVICEID 
                     FROM DEVICEMASTER 
                     WHERE DEVICENO = @DEVICENUMBER)

    SELECT 
        REGISTRATIONNUMBER AS TRUCKNUMBER,
        CURRENTLOCATION AS CURRENTLOCATION, 
        CURRENTLATLNG AS CURRENTLATLNG 
    FROM 
        TRUCKMASTER 
    WHERE 
        DeviceID IN (SELECT DEVICEID 
                     FROM DEVICEMASTER 
                     WHERE DEVICENO = @DEVICENUMBER) 
GO
```

Comment: U have began a transaction but didn't ended it.  add end keyword

Comment: Also you didn't used @DeviceID variable after assigning value to it. I have added the formatted version of your code in answers check it.

Answer (score 1):

I have added below changes to your stored proc.
 a). `END` keyword added.
 b). Value assigned variable `@DEVICEID` is used
 c). Formatting changes.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].PROC_GMAPSDATA
 (
 @DEVICENUMBER INT
 )
 AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @DEVICEID INT;

      SET @DEVICEID =(
                      SELECT 
                      DEVICEID 
                      FROM [dbo].[DEVICEMASTER] 
                      WHERE DEVICENO = @DEVICENUMBER
                      )

      SELECT REGISTRATIONNUMBER AS TRUCKNUMBER,
             CURRENTLOCATION    AS CURRENTLOCATION, 
             CURRENTLATLNG      AS CURRENTLATLNG 
      FROM [dbo].[TRUCKMASTER] 
      WHERE DeviceID = @DEVICEID

      SET NOCOUNT OFF;
   END
 GO
```